# Github Rest API authentication

Tags: rest, github, github-api

I have been using the GITHUB REST API for data mining. I followed the steps provided by GitHub to generate a token through the "Developer Settings". However, upon testing the newly generated token, I found that I am still limited to 60 requests per hour. My understanding was that authenticated users should receive a limit of 5000 requests per hour. I am not sure which part of the process I might have missed to fully authenticate my account.

Thank you very much, I have provided the code I used for testing how many tokens I get:

```
headers = {'Authorization': f'Token {token}'}

response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/rate_limit', headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    rate_limit_info = response.json()
    limit = rate_limit_info['resources']['core']['limit']
    remaining = rate_limit_info['resources']['core']['remaining']
    print(f'Limit: {limit}, Remaining: {remaining}')
else:
    print(f'Response returned with status code {response.status_code}: {response.text}')
```

Comment: Can you tell us whether you generated a classic or new-style token, and what permissions (scopes or otherwise) you gave it?  It sounds like maybe you don't have the right permissions on the token.

Comment: I generated classic token, I have tried all options